# Is there any good auto-complete gem available for rails3.2?

Tags: autocomplete, tags, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is there any good auto-complete gem available for rails3.2?
If possible, the one supporting multiple tags auto-complete with x button.
Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete this one I used, worked well in rails 3.2 or you can go to http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=autocomplete if you have premium account at RailsCasts.

Comment: Thanks!!! But the problem is what I'm looking is the auto-complete for multiple tags support.like this <http://webspirited.com/tagit/>. This one was kinda hard for me to implement so that I'm looking for easy one:)

Comment: Now I'm using the gem 'acts_as_taggable_on_steroids'. This covers multiple tags at once. That's why I wish I could find out any auto-complete plugin for this. <http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association-revised> this is so similar. But I'm not sure if it covers 'acts_as_taggable_on_steroids' because of delimitter thing.

Comment: take a look at this http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields-revised  and demo here http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/ ,  source code of this episode at https://github.com/railscasts/258-token-fields-revised  if you don't have a premium account at railscasts